# Problems assigning variable to the return of a function

Tags: java

I have been searching online for solutions to this problem for hours, but cannot find one. I am a beginner with java so I don't understand many of the errors and this is why I wasn't able to correct this myself.

Anyway, I am trying to assign a value to variable and then add the int value from the variable to another. When compiling I am getting errors: "this is not a statement" and an error that I missing a semicolon which I suspect will be cleared up if I fix the statement.

Here is the error, just in case you need it:

```
hw8_ex2_jm2rv.java:61: error: ';' expected
        int sumOfGames += value;
                      ^
hw8_ex2_jm2rv.java:61: error: not a statement
        int sumOfGames += value;
                          ^
2 errors
```

This is my code:

```
public static int oneGame()
{
    int trueValue = 1;
    int falseValue = 0;
    int total = sumTwoDice();
    if((total == 7) || (total == 11))
    {
        //System.out.println(trueValue  + " " + total);
        return(trueValue);
    }
    else if((total == 2) || (total == 3) || (total == 12))
    {
        //System.out.println(falseValue + " " + total);
        return(falseValue);
    }
    else
    {
        int total2 = 0;
        while((total2 != 7) || (total2 != total))
        {
            total2 = sumTwoDice();
            if(total2 == total)
            {
                //System.out.println(trueValue + " " + total + " " + total2);
                return(trueValue);

            }
            else if(total2 == 7)
            {
                //System.out.println(falseValue + " " + total + " " + total2);
                return(falseValue);

            }
        }
    }

}
```

You are probably wondering about the sumTwoDice method, all it does is return a number between 2 and 12 and I already know that it is working.If you want to see it I can post it too, just ask.

The oneGame function just simulates a game of craps and returns an integer value 1 or 0. With 1 being a win and 0 being a loss.

```
//this method runs a simulation of n values and returns the avg.
public static double monteCarloSim() 
{
    int trueValue = 1;
    int falseValue = 0;
    int sumOfGames = 0;
    int n = 2;
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        int value = oneGame();
        int sumOfGames += value;

    }
    double avg = sumOfGames / n;
    return(avg);
}
```

I just have a small n at the moment so that it is easier to deal with and faster to compile.

My main question is about what makes this statement invalid and what can I do do fix it, but also since many of the threads don't cover this on stack overflow, What makes **a** statement invalid in general. Hopefully this will help both me and other beginners that don't understand this error.

Thanks in advance for your help and knowledge!

Comment: Wow! I can't believe I missed that, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Declare your sum variable outside the loop:

```
int sumOfGames = 0;
```

The increment the value inside the loop:

```
int sumOfGames = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
{
    int value = oneGame();
    sumOfGames += value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should understand the difference between declaration and assignment.
Declaration is: `int sumOfGames;`, or you can also declare and assign, like you are doing: `int sumOfGames = 0;`.
But you can't and don't need to declare the variable more than once. So in your loop you should not be using `int`. This will look like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
{
    value = oneGame();
    sumOfGames += value;

}
```

Remember, that you need to **declare** the variable first and then **assign** it once or more. So in your case the whole method looks like:

```
public static double monteCarloSim() 
{
    /* declaration of variables */
    int trueValue = 1;
    int falseValue = 0;
    int sumOfGames = 0;
    int n = 2;
    int value; //this is what you have been missing
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        value = oneGame();
        sumOfGames += value;
    }
    double avg = sumOfGames / n;
    return(avg);
}
```

Also your loop can be shortened by not using additional variable:

```
public static double monteCarloSim() 
{
    /* declaration of variables */
    int trueValue = 1;
    int falseValue = 0;
    int sumOfGames = 0;
    int n = 2;
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        sumOfGames += oneGame();
    }
    double avg = sumOfGames / n;
    return(avg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `int` part of

```
int sumOfGames += value;
```

So it becomes

```
sumOfGames += value;
```

You can't use a compound assignment operator in a variable declaration - the whole point of a compound assignment operator is that it uses the previous value. Even if you *could* do that, it would clash with the previous declaration of `sumOfGames` in the same method.

As a matter of style, it's worth noting that you're using more brackets than you need to - sometimes that can *aid* readability, but it can also hurt it. For example, instead of:

```
if((total == 7) || (total == 11))
{
    //System.out.println(trueValue  + " " + total);
    return(trueValue);
}
```

I would write:

```
if (total == 7 || total == 11)
{
    //System.out.println(trueValue  + " " + total);
    return trueValue;
}
```

As for what makes *a* statement invalid in general - it's if it violates the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/index.html) rules in some way. There are lots of different ways that can happen, ranging from lexical and syntactic errors (things that simply don't make any sense, like `x..y` in an expression) to things that are syntactically valid, but semantically invalid (e.g. trying to invoke a method that doesn't exist, or trying to invoke a method that *does* exist, but where the call is ambiguous due to multiple overloads being valid but no one overload being better than the others).